# Check if the Checkbox is checked or no in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to check if the checkbox is checked or no.
I have the following code:

```
<div class="checkbox">
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VehicleTypeSelected)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleTypeSelected)    
<br>
@foreach (VehicleType vt in ViewBag.VehicleTypes)
{
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="@vt.VehicleTypeID" name="VehicleTypeIds" class="vehicle-type-selector" /> @vt.Name 
    <br></label>
}
```

I want to use this approach:

```
                    $('#checkBoxForm :checkbox').click(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
                        // the checkbox was checked 
                    } else {
                        // the checkbox was unchecked
                    }
                });
```

if the checkbox (isUniversal) is checked, I want to disable all the checkboxes(vehicleTypes)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if any vehicle type is checked, using just this:

```
$(function(){
    var isAnyVehicleTypeChecked = $(".vehicle-type-selector").is(":checked").length > 0
});
```

Furthermore, using the following

```
$(function(){
    var checkedVehicleTypes = $(".vehicle-type-selector").is(":checked");        
});
```

you can pick all the checkboxes that has the class vehicle-type-selector and they are checked.

Comment: where should I use this ?

Comment: It is a good practice to place a script at the bottom of your view. A far better approach is you define a section area in the bottom of your layout view and the use this section to append your script.

Comment: I have already defined a section at the bottom and I put your code, then how to use it with my code above ?

Comment: That depends on what you wan to do. You see if any vehicle type is checked or you take all the checked vehicle types. Then what?

Comment: please check my question again i edited it, i want to use that approach

Answer (score 0):

use the `attr()` function

Try (assuming `isUniversal` is a class ):

```
$(".isUniversal").on('click',function(){
      if ($("this").attr('checked') == 'checked') {
        $('.vehicle-type-selector').removeAttr('checked').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
      }
    })
```

or

```
 $(".isUniversal").on('click',function(){
              if( $('this').is(":checked") ){
                $('.vehicle-type-selector').removeAttr('checked').attr('disabled','disabled');
              }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $('.vehicle-type-selector').is(":checked") ){
  // Do something
}
```